Is there a difference in pronunciation between "It'd be" and "It be"?
I want to master pronouncing contractions to sound more natural. I think I know the technique to pronounce "It'd be", but to be honest, I'm not sure if it makes much difference to add a stop d after it.
So, are they different? Would you notice immediately if somebody said "It be" instead of "It'd be"?

"it be" is grammatically incorrect in standard BrE, although it can be found in some dialects. So yes, it would be noticeable.
As an aside there is the following dialect exchange:-
How be? [How are you]
I be, how be you? [I'm well, how are you?]

Hmm I'm actually asking about pronunciation. So you meant to say that native speakers can clearly distinguish between "it'd be" and "it be" in speech?

Yes, if spoken without any significant dialect or accent influence. A native BrE speaker would certainly notice the "d" sound or it's absence in say, RP.

@PeterJennings - will it be possible to use my UK mobile phone in Canada?

How would you expect to pronounce "it" in fast speech before a consonant, e.g. "it be"? Based on my own UK speech, it's unlikely to be [ɪt]. It could be reduced to [ɪʔ] (glottal stop) or just [ɪ] with a following consonant. So there's going to be a clear difference between "it" and "it'd".

@PeterJennings - could it be that your statement is over broad?

Is the glottal stop something of British accent? I follow AA, so is it weird if I use glottal stop?

@StuartF Oh and just in case, you mean that it'd be can be pronounced as /ɪbɪ/, don't you?

@MichaelHarvey Oops! I missed that possibility.

@PeterJennings: Re: "grammatically incorrect in standard BrE" - I think you're assuming that there's only one possible context, i.e. "it be" having the same meaning as "it'd be". But there are other possible contexts for "it be", which (as far as I'm aware) are widely considered totally standard. Example: "Whispered words of wisdom: Let it be".

@BobVesterman. Yes, I agree, Michael Harvey has already pointed this out and I've put my hand up to the error.

It sounds like you might have been thinking that it'd could be pronounced in one syllable as [ɪtd], but that pronunciation seems unlikely to me. I would also advise against pronouncing it'd in one syllable as [ɪt] (like it).
You can pronounce it in two syllables, with the  'd corresponding to the sound [əd] (references: Blog post by phonetician John Wells; Teflpedia). For me, as an American English speaker, the t of it would be voiced and "flapped/tapped" in this context because of the following vowel sound: [ɪɾəd]. In other accents, the pronunciation with two syllables might sound like [ɪtəd]. The reason for the apostrophe in this case is to represent the absence of the [w] consonant sound, not to indicate that there is no vowel sound between the t and d.
My intuition is that in quick speech, I often pronounce it'd in one syllable as [ɪd]. Wells mentions [ðæd] as a possible pronunciation of that'd. (He also says "maybe ðæt", but my intuition disagrees with him here.)
When a vowel sound follows, it'd could sound the same as it for me due to flapping/tapping. For example, I think my pronunciation of "It'd have been..." could be transcribed as [ɪɾəvbɪn] (which to my ears sounds like /ɪdəvbɪn/). But in it'd be, the following sound is a consonant: in this position, the distinction between word-final /t/ and /d/ can generally be clearly heard.
You could also keep in mind that when a /d/ sound comes before another plosive consonant in English, the /d/ may have its release "masked" by the second consonant, resulting in a pronunciation that sounds like it has the same "place of articulation" as the second plosive. In this case, that would make it sound like [b]. So [ɪɾədbi] or [ɪdbi] could sound like [ɪɾəbbi] or [ɪbbi] respectively. I'd hesitate to recommend aiming for a pronunciation with [bb] as a target, though: I think I've read that some studies have found native English speakers may actually still put their tongues in the position for making a [d] sound in contexts like this, even if it's hard to acoustically detect this [d] before the following [b]. (Nevertheless, some descriptions do call this a form of assimilation.)

In my UK SouthEast enunciation,  even in very relaxed conversational contexts, there'd usually be a clear glottal stop in it'd be for the "under-enunciated" 'd = would element. I can't deny that if I was sufficiently tired / drunk it might be indistinguishable from it be, but hopefully anyone I'm talking to would know that no amount of booze could turn me into a West Country yokel or stereotypical pirate ("Yarrrgh! It be obvious this be pirate speech!)

@FumbleFingers Heck, I could imagine that glottal stop as even swallowing the "t", for "i'be."

Thank you so much! This is really enlightening. But now there's another problem. According to your guidance, I feel like in fast speech it'd be and it'll be are really hard to be distinguished. The pronunciations are [ɪɾədbi] and [ɪɾəlbi]. I know that for native speakers it might be obvious, but for us learners they sound really similar in fast speech since you don't spend so much time pronouncing the "l" sound. When pronouncing it'll be in fast speech, I have to transition quickly from the "l" sound to the "b" sound, ...

...making it incomplete and hence almost indistinguishable from [ɪɾədbi]. Any tips here?

By the way, you said "...one syllable as [ɪtd], but that pronunciation seems unlikely to me", but then "in quick speech, I often pronounce "it'd" in one syllable as [ɪd]". So how is [ɪtd] different from [ɪd]? Or do you mean that [ɪtd] is only unlikely in slow speech?

@Andy Bonner: Absolutely. I don't fully enunciate many /t/'s, and I'd almost never enunciate anything more than two rapid consecutive /d/'s for the /t/ and contracted '/d/ in That'd be for me when the phone rings for a call I'm expecting. I admit to someone else, it might sound as if I'm just saying That be for me, but in my mind, I've at least made a token effort to avoid sounding too much like a yokel!

@AnIELTSLearner: You don't need any special tips to know how to hear the difference between contracted It'd be... and It be... Whether clearly enunciated or not, and regardless of how well you hear any "minimally-articulated" sounds, if you're listening to a native speaker you should assume they know English grammar perfectly well, and will only be using the "syntactically correct" form. And you yourself should always enunciate the correct form, or you'll just sound weird.

@FumbleFingers Today’s XKCD is timely

@AndyBonner: Good one! I must admit potato is one of those words that virtually forces me to articulate both /t/'s (it's not really possible to use a glottal stop for either of them). But if the preceding word is hot, the final /t/ there would normally be a minimally-articulated glottal stop for me. As opposed to Hot and cold, where the glottal stop would be quite pronounced (but almost never an actual /t/ for me).

@AnIELTSLearner: The difference is that [ɪtd] would have a voiceless [t] sound, which I'm saying is unlikely when I pronounce it'd as one syllable. As for distinguishing [ɪɾədbi] and [ɪɾəlbi], you're right that they don't sound similar to me, so I'm not sure about tips. It might help to keep in mind that many speakers pronounce /l/ as "dark l" before a consonant, so it'll be would likely be pronounced as [ɪɾəɫbi] or [ɪdɫ̩bi].

If it's a voiceless "t", how does it make a difference?

@AnIELTSLearner: I meant "voiceless" in the phonetic sense in my previous comment: a voiceless consonant is audible but is pronounced without vibration of the vocal cords. The word "bat" ends with a voiceless consonant [t] while the word "bad" ends with a voiced consonant [d].

Oh I see what you mean. But don't the voiceless "t" and "d" sound the same? For example, ladder and latter in American English sound exactly the same to me. I have even tried listening to the audios of these two words in Oxford dictionaries, and they do sound the same. In fact, I suspect they use the same audio for both words. Here're the links: latter and ladder

@AnIELTSLearner: In latter, the /t/ sound has been turned into [ɾ] (which is a voiced consonant sound) because the consonant is between two vowels. In contrast, when /t/ is followed by a consonant, as in football, it isn't pronounced as [ɾ] and so doesn't sound the same as /d/. So bat would sound like [bæɾ] in a sentence like "There's a bat on the wall" (next word starts with a vowel) but it would sound like [bæt], not [bæɾ] in a sentence like "There's a bat next to the door" (next word starts with a consonant).

@AnIELTSLearner: Likewise, it is pronounced like [ɪɾ] in a sentence like "It is," but is pronounced [ɪt] not [ɪɾ] in a sentence like "it was".

Oh sorry, I think I exemplified my point poorly in my above comment. The words should be letdown and led down. I see no difference in the pronunciations of these two words. I'm comparing [etd] and [ed] here, and I think the same comparison can apply to the case of itd and id.

@AnIELTSLearner: Ah, I see! This might be worth a separate question. There is a difference in pronunciation between "letdown" (or "let down") and "led down". The sequence [td] can't occur at the end of a syllable, but it can occur between syllables: "let down" is pronounced [lɛt.daʊn] which sounds different from [lɛd.daʊn] (using [.] to mark a syllable boundary).

@AnIELTSLearner: Actually, I just remembered an answer I wrote that's somewhat related to this topic but it's a bit technical: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/92976

Yes, it is indeed. I wonder if you're interested in talking about this further if I ask a question in response to your other answer.

In my pronunciation (native North New Jersey), at least, "it'd" is two quick, short syllables; they're almost the same as each other, except a "d" in the second instead of a "t". Like, "it-idd", quickly. Or, if I'm not really carefully enunciating, probably even really indistinguishable from each other, like "iddidd".
I'd be surprised to hear someone pronounce it in a single syllable -- if I noticed.

So for you it's, it'd is pronounced as [ɪɾidbi], not [ɪɾədbi]?

@AnIELTSLearner, I'm sorry, I'm not good at interpreting IPA. I just did a little google search though, and came upon this video for pronunciation of "that'd, it'd, and what'd". The lady's pronunciations sound normal to my ear: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ii56xxJdPPM&t=150s
